# Create name/value pairs based on file output

Tags: bash

I'd like to format the output of `cat myFile.txt` in the form of:

```
app1=19
app2=7
app3=20
app4=19
```

Using some combination of piping output through various commands.
What would be easiest way to achieve this?
I've tried using `cut -f2` but this does not change the output, which is odd.

Here is the basic command/file output:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ cat myFile.txt
       1402483560882 app1                                    19
       1402483560882 app2                                    7
       1402483560882 app3                                    20
       1402483560882 app4                                    19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basing from your input:

```
awk '{ print $2 "=" $3 }' myFile
```

Output

```
app1=19
app2=7
app3=20
app4=19
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using sed and cut:

```
cat myFile.txt | sed 's/ \+/=/gp' | cut -f 3- -d '='
```

Or using tr and cut:

```
cat myFile.txt | tr -s ' ' '=' | cut -f 3- -d '='
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `sed` oneliner also,

```
$ sed 's/^\s*[^ ]*\s\([^ ]*\)\s*\(.*\)$/\1=\2/g' file
app1=19
app2=7
app3=20
app4=19
```